# Is it possible to do GPU programming if I have an integrated graphics card?

Tags: gpu

I have an HP Pavilion Laptop, it's so-called graphics card is some sort of integrated NVIDIA driver running on shared memory. To give you an idea of its capabilities, if a videogame was made in the last 5 years at a cost of more than a couple million dollars, it just won't be playable on my computer.

Anyways, I was wondering if I could do GPU programming, like CUDA, on this thing. I don't expect it to be fast, I'd just like to get the experience and not make my laptop catch fire in the meanwhile.

Answer (score 2):

Find out what GPU your laptop is, and compare it against this list: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA#Supported_GPUs. Most likely, CUDA will not be supported.

This doesn't necessarily prevent you from doing "GPU programming", however. If the GPU supports fragment and vertex shaders, you can use the fixed pipeline to send data to the card (for example, through texture data) and do your processing in a fragment shader. You will then do a read from the pixel buffer to get the data back into system memory. Though hackish, this approach was quite popular until CUDA and other frameworks like OpenCL were introduced.